# Django, let QuerySet methods to handle both queryset and list?

Tags: django, django-models

This has been haunting me for a long time and I couldn't find an answer for it.

I'm not sure how QuerySet is cached in general,
but `prefetch_related` is cached as a list.

If you want to further filter the `prefetch_related`, 
you either run a new `prefetch_related` query, or you can filter it on python level.

Sometimes it makes sense to do it the second way (filtering on python level) when it is expensive to run the query.

QuerySet's method works on queryset and returns queryset, 
but it's advantageous to work with prefetched cache (I want to do this not just for prefetch_related but queryset in general if possible).

I can think of something like,

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    @property
    def bars(self):

        if hasattr(self, 'bar_set_prefetched'):
            return self.bar_set_prefetched
        else:
            return self.bar_set.all()


class BarQuerySet(QuerySet):

    def is_visible(self):

        if prefetched:          # don't know how to detect
            return [bar for bar in self if bar.visible]

        return self.filter(is_visible=True)


class Bar(models.Model):

    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bar_set')
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)


# client code

foos = Foo.boejcts.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'bars',
        to_attr='bar_set_prefetched'
    )
)

for foo in foos:

    bars = foo.bars.is_visible()  # I want is_visible to use prefetched list instead of running new query
```

I'm not sure if its doable and want to know possible pitfalls that I need to be aware of.